# Export Images from SQL server via SSIS not working

Tags: sql-server, ssis, export, sql-server-data-tools

I am trying to follow a simple guide on how to export images from Microsoft SQL Server to my local disk. I can connect to the data source just fine but when I connect the "Export Column Transformation" task and open it to edit it I see no options. Is this a permission issue or something I am totally not thinking of? Any help would be great!

What I'm seeing:

[image]

What I should be seeing:

[image]

Comment: Which SQL Server version is your SSIS package targeting? It may be worth a try to downgrade from SQL 2019 / 2017 to SQL 2016. Right-click your SSIS project and to show its *Properties* and navigate to *Configuration Properties* to switch the `TargetServerVersion` property.

Comment: Are the images stored in varbinary? Are all the images the same type? like jpg or png or tiff?

Comment: Double click the line between your source and the Export Column Component. Click the `Metadata` tab, and post a screenshot of what you see

Comment: @Filburt I am thinking it is something closer to your answer because when I spin everything up on another computer and only add the Export Column Transformation it shows that customizable window even though I don't have anything connected to it. It feels like the versioning has gone crosseyed or packages weren't completely installed or some type of permission issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. select your data from a OleDB source.
2. Add a script component transform (it is really a destination)
3. Add your varbinary column to readOnly input column
4. Add this code:

   ```
   using(var ms = new MemoryStream((byte[]) Rows.varbinaryColumn))
   {
      System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, true)
      img.Save(@"c:\mydocuments\image.jpg");
   }
   ```

Note: `MemoryStream` is in `System.IO`

Comment: And if your dataset actually had the `FilePathColumn` as the reference image indicates, you would want to use that in the Save call. Otherwise, you'll overwrite the output file for every row sent. `img.Save(Rows.FilePathColumn);`